# plane equation from two 3D points and perpendicular distance between that plane and a point

Tags: c, math

I have three 3d points say A(x1,y1,z1), B(x2,y2,z2) and C(x3,y3,z3). How to get an equation of plane that passes through point A and B , then how to get perpendicular distance from point C to this plane. Perpendicular distance will be distance between plane passing through point C and parallel to plane b/w A and B. Is there any short way to implement these calculation, as I want these calculation to implement in code in C language with time of execution as major concern. 
 Main aim is to find perpendicular distance b/w C and plane containing A and B.

Comment: You need to add math tag to this. This is not a C question

Comment: Isnt there more than one plane passing through the two points?

Comment: There is an infinite number of planes passing through two points in a 3d space... You need at least three points which are not all on a line in order to define a plane.

Comment: As jacksparrow007 and smichak says, there are an infinite number of planes that share points A and B. I think you perhaps need to rethink the question

Comment: Concerning the equation herself, maybe you'll have more pertinent answers on [Maths Stackexchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/). When you will have the answer, here's the better place (according to me) to translate in C language.

Comment: Main aim of askin this question was to calculate perpendicular distance from C to plane of A and B. if there are many plane , consider any 1 plane , and how to find perpendicular distance from a plane which is parallel to this plane and contains point C in it...

Comment: @ParitoshBairagi: Draw a plane that goes through A, B *and* C (you can *always* draw a plane through *any* three points). Then perpendicular distance from the plane to C becomes 0. Nothing to calculate. '0' is one of the valid answers. **What I am trying to point out is, that your question is flawed**.

Comment: This question is pointless - I can specify plane ABC then your answer is zero.

Comment: @mathematician1975 :-) ; Paritosh It is however possible to calculate the perpendicular distance between a plane passing through any given *3 points (say A, B, C)* and a *4th* given point (say D). It is *also* possible to find the perpendicular distance between a *line* passing through any given two points (say A, B), and a third given point (say C)

Answer (score 1):

2 points define a *line*.
You can always choose a plane including both that line and point `C`, hence the distance is always zero.

The C you're looking for is something like:

```
struct Point {
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
};

double perpendicular_distance(struct Point *a, struct Point *b, struct Point *c)
{
    return 0.0;
}
```

Seriously, understand the maths first.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is underconstrained as written.  There are an infinte number of planes containing the two points A and B; the distance to any third point P will be in the range [0, X] where X is the distance between P and the line connecting points A and B.  So, if all you're interested in doing is finding the distance between the point P and the line connecting A and B, [there's an algorithm for that](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance3-Dimensional.html).  This will also uniquely define the plane containing A and B which is most distant from P.